# How to refresh the parent ASPX control values without refreshing whole page?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I have two ASPX pages .. One is the parent, and the other is the child ... the parent ASPX has a link which opens the child ASPX in a new window, using the code below:

**Code used to open the popup ASPX:**

```
//JavaScript function:
function showPopup()
{
     var strReturn = window.open("TaxReportInputsForm.aspx",'popup','width=390,height=120');
}
```

**Button code:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", "showPopup();", true);
```

I'm currently using the child form's code-behind, to set the values of the parent form's controls, using Session variables ... However the problem is that even though the parent form's control's value updates (confirmed through debugging), it doesn't 'show' the new value ..

How can I make the parent form's control's show their new value, after the child form changes a value ?

**Two requirement:**

1. Note that I want the parent form's control's values to update while
   the child form is still open .. That is, I don't want to wait for
   the child form to close, in order to trigger this update ..
2. I also don't want the entire parent form to refresh, because that
   causes all control's values to reset ..

My framework is .NET 2.0 ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is not communication between the Parent client side code to its code-behind code. It is the reason that values are not updated in the html (client). Now the solution is making the communication between client side code and server

1) Jquery AJAX call with timer setup. Timer will only start after you have open the child popup. Now the value from the server can come to client side and updated by jquery DOM changes

2) PageMethod of ASP.NET can also be used.

Comment: I can't use jQuery ... Can you explain the second option though briefly ?

Comment: You have to ajaxtool kit supplied by Microsoft Check it here : http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/12/24/page-methods-in-asp-net.aspx